# FFXIII menu cursor moves on its own

Tags: controllers, final-fantasy-13

When the main menu of FFXIII loads up the cursor keeps moving between START and SETTINGS by itself. If i time it right i can go to SETTINGS and the cursor is stuck on the top. If i hold down arrow it goes down, and as soon as i release it it goes up again.

I have searched the internet for a while now and all the solutions say disconnect your gamepad and uninstall any virtual gamepads. This does not fix my issue and the menu cursor keeps moving.

- I had Input Mapper because i want to use a PS4 controller. Uninstalled. Rebooted.
- I also have DS4Windows but it is just an .exe, not installed and not running.
- Game controllers list in control panel is empty.
- All USB devices disconnected.
- No Bluetooth devices.
- Keyboard cannot be disconnected (laptop).

What now?

Comment: Could it be that one of your keyboard keys is stuck permanently pressing up? I had a similar issue with my Windows key, pressing the key 2 or 3 times seems to release the key. I'd suggest trying that with whatever key is up on FF XIII.

Comment: @JoãoNeves Thanks but i already tried that, all the arrow keys and the numpad, numlock on & off. No issues in any other software.

Comment: How about the WASD keys?

Comment: Nope, still not working and i would have noticed if those were stuck :)

Comment: I've no idea then. Good luck, hope you can find a solution!

Comment: @MaciejSwic Could be the controller itself, you tried using it on any other games?

Comment: Yes, i also tried without the controller (no USB devices connected at all)